# Subscribe does not exist of type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angualr 2. And I am making a small application for practice. I have a service for authentication of users when they log in. And here is it's login function.

```
login(email:string, password:string){

        var loginrul="https://filing.herokuapp.com/api/v1/auth/login/";
        return this.http.post(loginrul,JSON.stringify({  password: password,email: email }),
            {headers:new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})}
            ).map(res=>res.json()).
            subscribe(
                data => localStorage.setItem('id_token',data.auth_token),
                error=>console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

When I call this function in component angualr gives error that "Property subscribe does not exist on type 'Subscription'.

```
doLogin(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(this.loginForm.value);


        let formData = this.loginForm.value;
        let email = this.loginForm.controls.email.value;
        let password= this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
        this.auth.login(email,password).subscribe(res =>{
            console.log(res);
            if(res.status===200){
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            }
        }
        )
    }
```

I think why angular is giving this error because i am using subscribe in login function as well as while calling login function. Please suggest some solution or an alternative approach to achieve the result which I am trying to achieve in login function.

Comment: Just Return the map() and subscribe at the caller

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your own analysis of the problem is correct! Remove the `.subscribe` in your service and only use it in your component where you consume it. Your service should return after the `.map` operator.

If you subscribe in the service, it will return an `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`, and that's indeed why you are getting your error.

Comment: if i move data => localStorage.setItem('id_token',data.auth_token) in to component will auth_token be available here?

Comment: If it comes from the data in the request then it should be available - yes

Comment: I came across to your answer. I have a page/component trying to subscribe a svc, and svc is calling `HttpClient` to do a Post. Since `HttpClient` returns an observable so I do `.subscribe()` inside svc too, got **Subscribe does not exists of type 'Subscription'**. Removing `.subscribe() from svc` works. It seems just need to subscribe at the very beginning no matter how many component/svc between. Right?