# Getting null response from post request though request processed successfully

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

I am hitting a `post` request using `httpClient`, but getting `null` response though request processing Successfully.

`serviceClass.ts` file

```
this.httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'tenant-code' : 'VdoFWiHL8RFR8fRGNjfZI=',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('pass:username')
    })
}

public Reprocess(ObjProduct) {
var Jobj=JSON.stringify(ObjProduct);
return this._http.post(this.ReprocessUrl,Jobj,this.httpOptions)
}
```

When I am calling the above method in Component, I'm getting `null` response from API.

Component Code

```
var op = this.objService.reprocess(this.reprobj);
console.log("output: ", op);
```

Here `op` is completely incomprehensible, it's showing `_scaler=false` etc. How can I get correct status of the service call?

**Edit 1:** When I make same request from postman getting status `Ok 200`.

**Edit 2:** Below code also giving `null` result(as per the @Spart_Fountain's answer)

```
var op= this.restApi.Reprocess(this.reprobj).subscribe((data:any) => {
console.log("data "+ data);    
});
```

Postman header screenshot

[image]

Comment: How do you know it's successful? Where do  you check it?

Comment: bcz records are beings stored in database..

Comment: OK then, what is the server configured to send back? It's possible the server isn't programmed to send anything back to the client making the HTTP request.

Comment: I want http status like 'Ok'. I want to show msg to  user _Successfully created_ but without status I can't do that. Configuring server is not in my hand. When I am calling the same service from .Net application getting http response 'Ok'.

Comment: Try to make the same request through something like postman and see what the response is there. Also, inside the `subscribe` use `console.log("resp from api service: ", resp);` instead of adding them `+`. This forces the object's `toString()` method to be called (this is minor and probably not the problem).

Comment: I have already tried postman getting status 200 Ok

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your request Using inspect in networks tab from your browser and also the headers of your postman request. I want to compare these two requests. i think you are missing something in request. i was facing same issue and my problem was default headers in angular request were not same as POSTMAN.

Comment: You checked your `objParam` or `httpOptions` and compared them with your postman query?

Comment: Have you handled cors?

Comment: Can you show your httpoptions passed in post request? Also this is not the right way to handle service request, don't subscribe to observable in service itself, better subscribe to observable in your component.

Comment: @varundhariyal - please check my updated question.

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil -  please check my updated question.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya Can you please update your code so that it becomes consistent? You introduced the service (?) `restApi`, where is it defined and what does the `Reprocess` method return?

Comment: @SparkFountain - `restApi` is the object of `serviceClass.ts`

Comment: But the `serviceClass.ts` implementation (or at least a code stub) is also missing in your question. Please give us a chance to help you and provide a clean code base. Otherwise the community can only estimate where your problem lies.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you get a "strange looking" response when calling `this.objService.reprocess(this.reprobj);` is that this method will return a [Subscription](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription) object.

In detail: The method `reprocess` returns a subscription to an observable, because the method `subscribe()` is called inside of the `return` statement itself. What you would rather do is to return only the observable and subscribe to it outside of the `reprocess` method:

```
public reprocess(objProduct) {
  var objParam = JSON.stringify(objProduct);
  return this._http.post(this.url, objParam, this.httpOptions);
}

var op = this.objService.reprocess(this.reprobj).subscribe(resp => {
  console.log("resp from api service: " + resp);
});
```

Comment: If I use `subscribe` here getting error `node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscription.d.ts:39:5 unsubscribe(): void;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~
'unsubscribe' is declared here.`

Comment: `error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?`

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya You can only subscribe to an Observable, not to a Subscription object (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44687038/2764486)). In other words: Do not *double subscribe*! The service should always return an Observable without subscription.

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet you have posted also looks fine and you have already checked your backend API is working fine and your database is getting updated when you call the API using postman.

1. Is your database getting updated when you are using the above method to hit the API?
   If not then there is a problem in frontend. Check if you are passing the right parameters to the post method.
2. If your database is getting updated when you are using the above method but not getting a response. Then probably your API does not send any response. You might want to look at your API code.

Comment: Extra confusing with FastAPI, which always returns a JSONResponse by default, meaning you see a response with the string `null` instead of no response at all. Return a `Response(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)` instead. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/717#issuecomment-583826657

Answer (score 2):

Actually, null value you got in log is a proper behavior of http client. By default it observe only a response body. So that means you alreday got a 200 OK status and an empty body in response. To observe a whole response you can do hext:

```
   this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'tenant-code' : 'VdoFWiHL8RFR8fRGNjfZI=',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('pass:username')
        }),
        {
          observe: 'response'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.objectService.reprocess(this.reprObj).subscribe(resp => {
   console.log(resp);
})
```

The above one will subscribe to method reprocess. And in reprocess method:
import statement:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

reprocess(objProduct) {
   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('object', objProduct)
   return(
     this.http.post(this.url, formData)
   )
}
```

On your server side, pull the objProduct.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to subscribe to Reprocess function.

Also add an error callback function where your subscribe to log any errors returned from your post attempt.

Also run developer tools for your browser and check the Network tab to see the requests / responses and headers being sent when making the request from your Angular app.

Look for the following in your Network tab response headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
  (Your url e.g. localhost:4200)

To verify that your request is allowed fro your origin.

Also check in case error shown for 'WWW-Authenticate:' e.g. invalid token.

Make the call to subscribe from your component to the service Reprocess function like:

```
this.objService.reprocess(this.reprobj).subscribe(result =>
{
console.log(result);
},
error => {
 console.log(error);
}
);
```

You can also amend the service function to explicitly show what is being returned (Observable to subscribe to):

```
public reprocess(objProduct): Observable<any> {
  var objParam = JSON.stringify(objProduct);
  return this._http.post<any>(this.url, objParam, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Make sure Observable is imported into your service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

As it's working from Postman and you are confident the credentials are correct, focus on the code changes I have shown, especially making sure Observable is imported then the function is called with subscribe. If you add the Observable return type without the import, you will see it highlighted in your code as an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public reprocess(objProduct) {
 var objParam = JSON.stringify(objProduct);
 return this._http.post(this.url, objParam,this.httpOptions);
 }`var op = this.objService.reprocess(this.reprobj).subscribe(resp =>{
 console.log("resp from api service: " + resp);
 });
```